# YARN JobHistory Error : Failed redirect for container

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2, hortonworks-data-platform, cloudera-cdh

We recently deployed YARN with CDH 5 (2.3.0-cdh5.1.3), cluster is running file, jobs are also running.
But we are not able to access logs from Resource manager UI if job is completed (SUCCEEDED/FAILED), we are getting following error

```
Failed redirect for container_1412716537481_0322_01_000001
Failed while trying to construct the redirect url to the log server. Log Server url may not be configured
Container does not exist.
```

Also some exception for running jobs :

```
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException): Permission denied: user=mapred, ac
cess=READ, inode="/user/history/done_intermediate/xyz/job_1412716537481_0426-1412782860181-xyz-PigLatin%3ACategory+li
ft+for+pixels%3A9259-1412782882528-1-1-SUCCEEDED-root.brianfemiano-1412782867082.jhit":xyz:supergroup:-rwxrwx---
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkFsPermission(FSPermissionChecker.java:271)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.check(FSPermissionChecker.java:257)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkPermission(FSPermissionChecker.java:185)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkPermission(FSNamesystem.java:5607)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkPermission(FSNamesystem.java:5589)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkPathAccess(FSNamesystem.java:5551)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getBlockLocationsUpdateTimes(FSNamesystem.java:1717)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getBlockLocationsInt(FSNamesystem.java:1669)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getBlockLocationsUpdateTimes(FSNamesystem.java:1717)         [1804/1922]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getBlockLocationsInt(FSNamesystem.java:1669)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getBlockLocations(FSNamesystem.java:1649)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getBlockLocations(FSNamesystem.java:1621)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.getBlockLocations(NameNodeRpcServer.java:482)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.getBlockLocations(ClientNamenodeProtocolServe
rSideTranslatorPB.java:322)
```

What are the appropriate permissions on hdfs://user/history/ ?

anyone having same issue ?

Answer (score 1):

I think your cluster is Secured (Kerberos-enabled) and for HTTP authentication in secure env you need to set the below parameters.
Refer
http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.0.6.0/ds_Hadoop/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/HttpAuthentication.html

-Arun voma

Comment: No we don't have any security/kerberos, its more related to YARN permissions i think.